# post request only returns "hash" and WebView returns "null"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, http-post, android-webview

I tried to parse one site but one request only returns me "hash".

My request: (you may need a vpn to send requests)
manga.in.ua/engine/ajax/controller.php?mod=load_chapters&action=show&news_id=6590&news_category=1&this_link=""&site_login_hash=trefkbo756dsvnrfh4vhgfi654

I analyzed an html page that dynamically adds a list of sections using javascript ->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const news_id = $("#linkstocomics").data("news_id");
    const news_category = $("#linkstocomics").data("news_category");
    const this_link = news_category === 54 ? $("#linkstocomics").data("this_link") : "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "/engine/ajax/controller.php?mod=load_chapters",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
   data: {action:'show',
         news_id:news_id,
         news_category:news_category,
         this_link:this_link,
         user_hash:site_login_hash},
        success: function(data) {
             //the logic of processing the received data
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I was able to find the required keys for news_id, news_category, this_link and site_login_hash, but in the end it always returns me "hash".

I changed some data and checked if the key for site_login_hash (marked as PHPSESSID in the cookie) changes with each new request, usually it is static, but sometimes I see its value changing in the cookie.

I'm not using selenium because I'm building an android app and I can't be sure that the user will have the right browser version. Tried using a regular webView as well, but when executing the js it returns null to me for some reason.

```
val myJsFun = "$(document).ready(function() ......"
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript(myJsFun){
            Log.i("info", it.toString())
        }
    }
}

Logcat:
info: null
```

In general, I would like to run this function in one of these ways, webView or post request, but at the moment I'm not getting anything and I don't understand where exactly I made a mistake. I will be grateful for any tips

**UPDATE #1 (WebView)**

I tried some webView usages, but every time I try to return the HTML I get an error. My code:

```
val web: WebView? = WebView(requireActivity())
web?.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true

web?.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){
    override fun doUpdateVisitedHistory(view: WebView?, url: String?, isReload: Boolean) {
        view?.evaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.outerHTML"){
            val html = it.replace("\\u003C", "<")
            Log.i("info", html.substring(html.indexOf("linkstocomics"), html.indexOf("linkstocomics") + 1000))
        }
    }

}
web?.loadUrl(//url);
```

but it returns null to me along with an error in Logcat: `(server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`

But if I change

```
val web: WebView? = WebView(requireActivity())
```

to

```
val web: WebView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.webview)
```

Then in the displayed webview itself, all elements are displayed correctly and the js completes its work correctly, however, if I again try to get a list of chapters at each change of the webview in the middle of `doUpdateVisitedHistory`, then HTML is returned to me that does not contain the information that was loaded by js.

Displaying the webview on the user's screen shows the elements that have been loaded by the javascript, but when I try to get the html of the page, I get the html without the js executed.